# HTML-email line-height for Outlook Web App

Tags: html-email

I'm working on a HTML e-mail template.
The line-height in the html code below seems to work fine in Gmail and Outlook.
However, in the Outlook Web App the line height is increased.
I tried some fixes I found on the internet/stackoverflow: the css code in the header and the inline css code.
However, this doesnt do the trick.
Does anybody know how to fix the line-height in the Outlook Web App for the example below?

Thanks! Mark

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100% !important;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400">
<tr>
<td width="400" style="display:block;padding:0px;margin:0px;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000000;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:12px;">
Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  
Test copy  Test copy Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  
Test copy Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  
Test copy  Test copy  Test copy Test copy  Test copy  
Test copy  Test copy Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  
Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy Test copy  
Test copy  Test copy  Test copy Test copy  Test copy  
Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy
Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy
Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  
Test copy  Test copy Test copy  Test copy  Test copy  
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix we've used but it looks like that may be similar to yours already.

```
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="15"
style="font-size:15px; line-height:15px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;"
class="hide">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```